# Batch - Trouble with Redirect within For Loop

Tags: batch-file

I'm having difficulty getting a command to run in a For Loop.  From a cmd prompt this works fine:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MakeMKV\makemkvcon64.exe" -r info | find "E:"
```

But, the following seems to have a syntax problem

```
for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=," %%A in ('"C:\Program Files (x86)\MakeMKV\makemkvcon64.exe" ^-r info ^| find "E:"') do (set _DRVID=%%A)
```

Yielding an error - `C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Just for reference, I found a way to get my desired result with the following:
I can get the following code to work in Batch as well generating the desired output:

```
for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=," %%A in ('"C:\Program Files (x86)\MakeMKV\makemkvcon64.exe" ^-r info') do (IF %%G=="E:" set _DRVID=%%A)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see any redirection in your code.

Comment: Is it really `^-r`, or is it a typo and should read `-r`? There is no need to escape `-`...

Comment: @Squashman, what about the pipe? Do you not consider such as redirecion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best work-around in my opinion is to place a pair of quoted quotation marks around the expression:

```cmd
for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=," %%A in ('^""C:\Program Files (x86)\MakeMKV\makemkvcon64.exe" ^-r info ^| find "E:"^"') do (set "_DRVID=%%~A")
```

After `for /F` consumes the enclosing `''`, the `cmd` instance executing the expression removes the outer-most `""`, so the remaining command line appears odd and therefore fails to be executed:

```cmd
C:\Program Files (x86)\MakeMKV\makemkvcon64.exe" ^-r info ^| find "E:
```

An extra pair of `""` fixed that, but then you need to change escaping. Adding a pair of escaped quotes `^"^"` lets the code work without having to change escaping. This is therefore the most general solution.

Answer (score 2):

when piping, both sides of a pipe are executed in an own instance of `cmd`. This makes quoting and escaping look non-intuitive. Try:

```
for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=," %%A in ('""C:\Program Files (x86^)\MakeMKV\makemkvcon64.exe" -r info | find "E:""') do (set _DRVID=%%A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm - after a little experimentation, I got this (or my version) to work:

```
for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"C:\Program Files (x86)\MakeMKV\makemkvcon64.exe" ^-r') do (
 for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=," %%A in ('ECHO(%%X^| find "E:"') do (set _DRVID=%%A)
)
```

But I've not been able to get the output of a quoted-executablename to be filtered as expected by the `find`.

Comment: you seem to have this EXE (I don't). could you please test my answer (especially, if escaping `-` is needed (I doubt it).

Comment: @stephan: I used a different executable in a path which included parentheses (which seems to be the root of the problem) to test both solutions.